# do not add next element if previous element isEmpty

Tags: flutter, dart

my application has a ListView that creates new items, but I need the following items not to be created if the previous item is empty

My Code:

```
void addSubItem() {
    final list = List<TaskSubItem>.from(state.list);

    if (list[0].name.isNotEmpty) {
      list.length++;
    }

    list.add(
      const TaskSubItem(
        name: '',
        status: '1',
      ),
    );
    state = state.copyWith(
      list: list,
    );
  }
```

Comment: Why don't you check list[index-1]?

Comment: I have tried , but i don't know how did right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright, maybe I understood what you want:

First of all, don't set the length of the list. The language will deal with it.

```
void addSubItem() {
    final list = List<TaskSubItem>.from(state.list);

 

if (list.elementAt(list.length-1).name.isNotEmpty {
    list.add(
      const TaskSubItem(
        name: '',
        status: '1',
      ),
    );
    state = state.copyWith(
      list: list,
    );
  }
}
```